# Unity Can't Do Ground Check with Objected Generated at Start Time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game that generates a maze at the start of the game. The player is dropped into the maze from a height of about 10 feet or so. The problem is that if I click the player object and change the inspector from normal to debug, I see that the character is still continuously generating falling velocity. I have a sphere at the bottom of the character that is supposed to do a ground check but clearly that isn't working. This is the relevant code for one of the ground tiles and the ground check features of the character.

Ground Tile Code in GameManager.cs in Scripts folder.

```
var tile = Instantiate(_tilePrefab);
tile.transform.Rotate(90, 0, 0);
tile.transform.localPosition = new Vector3((x * tileWidth) + offsetTile, 0, (y * tileWidth) + offsetTile);
tile.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground");
tile.transform.parent = _mazePrefab;
```

PlayerMovement.cs in Scripts folder

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 15f;
    public float gravity = -9.8f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y > 0)
        {
            velocity.y = 0f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I have a ground layer created and everything and I have an empty that projects a sphere at the base of my character.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never mind what I commented earlier. I found the problem and am writing my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem must be that your gravity resetting isn’t working. I suppose you are using the tutorial from Brackeys — I have used his tutorial before, so I know it works. The problem must be that your gravity resetting. So, I go through your code. I notice there is an if statement meant to reset the velocity when the player is grounded. So, I check the `isGrounded` variable. The only thing that could set that incorrectly is that the maze doesn’t have the right layer. Your code does set the layer right, so I rule that one out. I then look back at the if statement. The only thing that could set it off is the second term in it:

```cs
if (... && velocity.y > 0)
```

Notice how later in your code the velocity rapidly decreases.

```cs
velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
```

Notice how gravity is a negative variable.

```cs
float gravity = -9.8f;
```

And `Time.deltaTime` is positive. When multiplying positive and negative values, if the number of negative values in the equation is odd the result is negative, and if it is even the result is positive. Therefore, velocity decreases instead of increases.

In the if statement, you check if `velocity.y > 0`, in other words: if the velocity is **greater than** 0, do something. But according to the math, `velocity` is always *decreasing*, not *increasing*. But you are detecting if the velocity is above 0, not under it.

Change the if statement to:

```cs
if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
```

Notice how I change the `>` to a `<` to detect if it is less than zero.

---

That would solve your problem and you could go off here, but there is something else that is less important. Notice how after your if statement, you decrease the velocity.

```cs
...
if (isGrounded && velocity.y > 0)// «— if statement.
{
   velocity.y = 0f;
}

float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;// «—- change velocity.
...
```

Since after you call the if statement you change it, you won’t need to detect if the velocity is less than 0. This is because the velocity will always be slightly less than 0 at the end of each frame.

There are two things you could do here.

1. You could remove the second part of the if statement.
2. You could add the velocity change to the *else* of the if statement.

For 1:

```cs
if (isGrounded)
{
   velocity.y = 0f;
}
```

For 2:

Add:

```cs
if (isGrounded)
{
   velocity.y = 0f;
}
else
{
   velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

And remove:

```
controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

//removed this line «—-

controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: The second part I describe as ‘less important’ is optional, and may throw an error. If you get an error, then undo the second part.